# Mega.nz error in Ubuntu 19.04 fresh install

Tags: 19.04, mega

https://mega.nz Browser page loads but gives the following error in alert box and console.log in a fresh install ubuntu 19.04. Tested on both firefox and chromium.

```
MEGA failed to load because of 

The file "lang/en_4d49b6ef9deb8478b1b1545cee7d566d9264ddf90ce1505f62c128f899d9b08d.json" could not be loaded.

Please click OK to refresh and try again.

If the problem persists, please try disabling all third-party browser extensions, update your browser and MEGA browser extension to the latest version. If that does not help, contact support@mega.nz

BrowserID: mozilla/5.0 (x11; ubuntu; linux x86_64; rv:67.0) gecko/20100101 firefox/67.0

Static server: https://eu.static.mega.co.nz/3/
```

Comment: Please fully update Ubuntu and try again.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it i dont know how

Comment: The error message has a clue: "lang/en..." It suggests there was a problem with the locale and/or language support. You should always fully update any newly installed system and not start installing software right away.